# Elastic net is being used in genome wide analysis. Similar approach would work for survey analysis?

Tags: feature-selection, survey, multicollinearity, elastic-net, gwas

I'm approaching the elastic net procedure for genome wide analysis (GWAS) because it allows for feature selection, groups detection and improved validity.

It's a powerful technique when you have many features and you want to retain the most important ones.

In my opinion thus, GWAS looks a lot like survey analysis. Instead of many loci you have many questions, with probably many of them strongly correlated and often with few responders.

Does it make sense to use elastic net to select the most influential answers (or interaction of answers) related to an outcome?

Thanks